# Divergence of a second order tensor

Tags: tensor, differential-calculus

I think that I have found 2 seemingly conflicting sources relating to the divergence of a second order tensor. I am not sure which is correct.

Suppose you would like to compute the components of a simple second order tensor $\nabla \cdot \sigma$, where
$$ \sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} \\
 \sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

According wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_%28continuum_mechanics%29), the divergence of the tensor is written:

$$ \begin{align}
   \boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{S} &= \cfrac{\partial S_{ki}}{\partial x_k}~\mathbf{e}_i
   \end{align}
$$

To me, this means:
$$ \nabla \cdot \sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sigma_{11} & + & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\sigma_{21} \\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sigma_{12} & + &\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \sigma_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

However, I am reading (apparently a trusted) finite elements book by Gockenbach (Understanding and Implementing the Finite Element Method), which asserts that:

"The divergence of a tensor is the vector whose components are the divergences of the rows of the tensor:
$$ \nabla \cdot \sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sigma_{11} & + & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\sigma_{12} \\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sigma_{21} & + &\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \sigma_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
"

Clearly this can not be correct, since not every tensor is symmetric. What is going on?

Comment: This is definitely a matter of convention. Both definitions are sensible. However, I would always view vectors as columns, and therefor multiply scalars from the right. If you change the wikipedia definition that way, it actually becomes the other one. Thus, whenever you read a new textbook, first check for all the possibly ambiguous definitions.

Comment: Thank you. I have another suspicion that because the wikipedia page has a continuum mechanics focus, and have cited a source that talks about stress tensors. Since stress tensors are symmetric, it would make sense that either convention would suffice.